# How to use virtual environments without wasting disk space?

Tags: python, duplicates, virtualenv

I've watched many videos where they say we should have a new virtual environment for every Python project we make. When making new environments, I have to install my packages (numpy, matplotlib, etc.) over and over again. What can I do to keep these environments from using a lot of my computer's storage?

Comment: To create multiple global virtual environments you could use Anaconda/Miniconda. Create a new venv with a certain name, install the most used packages in it, activate the environment in a console when you need to launch your code. In case you break your environment, just delete it with no harm to the python's default environment

Comment: It's a tradeoff. If you use the same version of Pandas for a large number of projects, installing it system-wide probably makes more sense; but this forces you to accept this limitation (though of course you are still free to install a separate Pandas version in a virtualenv if you want to use a separate version in just a few places).

Comment: This may fare better on SESE?

Answer (score 11):

Well, you are right, virtual environments are somehow a waste of disk space because they are meant to create **isolated environments** that have -almost- no dependencies outside themselves.

E.g. if you have venvA and venvB, both can be using the same version of pckgX but, none of them will share it with the other and you will have the same pckgX installed in two different environments. However this is not an awful drawback, as in most cases you use python environments to have **different versions** of the **same package** in your machine and use them interchangeably, or that is why I use virtual environments.

It makes you comfortable when you modify or delete packages in your virtual environment with no worries that you may damage other ones.

However, we can **overcome this** by using caches and other methods:

- [In pip](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/pip-virtualenv/) we can cache downloads in `~/.pip/cache` so it won't need to download them again next time by adding the following to `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf`:

```
[global]
download_cache = ~/.pip/cache
```

- [In conda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/shared-pkg-cache/), you can use a shared package cache by creating a directory on your system where the shared users have read and write access.

Then, for each user who will have access, edit the `.condarc` file found in their home directory with the following entry, specifying the full path to that shared directory:

```
pkgs_dirs:
    - /path/to/shared_directory
```

> Windows - C:\Users\username.condarc
>
> macOS and Linux - /home/username/.condarc

Verify the package cache by running `conda info`.

Comment: Like Mostafa mentioned you use different versions of the same package a lot in development envirounments. Forinstance you have a product live with version 1. You need to maintain this so you have a venv with the correct packages for that first version. At the same time your are developing your product version 2 which has updated packages.

Comment: Having two, three or one hundred versions of the same library installed is extremely common in the most popular OSs and predate Python environments by several decades. At the present moment I have installed in my Linux box GCC 9,10,11,12 and 13; CUDA v. 10 - 12; SDL 1.2 and 2.0; GTK2 and GTK3, QT 4 and 5 and a long etc.
And somehow they manage to live happily side by side without reinstalling an extra copy of themselves every time I use them in a new project or task.
Meanwhile, every ML project folder is full of 40+Gb of duplicated clutter I cannot get rid of for no good reason.
Go figure.